# Как использовать переменную, обявленою вне обработчика аякс запроса

Tags: ajax, php

Здравствуйте. У меня такой вопрос: как использовать переменную, оглашенную вне обработчика яакс запроса?
У меня есть пхп скрипт, который генерирует часть страницы хтмл. С этой страницы я посылаю аякс запрос на свой пхп скрипт обратно. В скрипте есть проверка: если запрос аякс - делать тото, если нет - продолжается нормальная робота. У меня в массиве ПОСТ есть значение, которое присваевается переменной, к примеру item. Мне нужно внутри аякс обработчика иметь доступ к этой переменной , обявленой вне обработчика аякс запроса

Comment: Не могу удержаться и не сделать этого:  
http://i.imgur.com/mmTuC8W.png

Comment: Три раза перечитал, не понял вопроса. Вы хотите использовать переменную PHP в JS, а конкретнее в обработчике AJAX?

Comment: Может я несколько некорректно описал ситуацию) У меня из html скрипта идет запрос на php скрипт. Внутри php скрипта есть условие: если запрос аякс ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') то выполнить какие-то действия. В конце запроса exit.Так же, у меня в самом php скрипте есть переменная, которую я хочу использовать внутри обработчика ajax запроса. Прямого доступа к ней нет. Вот я и интересуюсь, есть ли способ получить данные этой переменной внутри обработчика ajax запроса

Comment: Назовем искомую переменную - $variable. Если $variable было объявлена в области видимости уровнем выше блока обработки ajax, то доступ к ней можно получить. [Пример][1]


  [1]: http://pastebin.com/9Usb4Vgq

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `global $var_name;` внутри функции или `use ($var_name)` при ее определении

Comment: Спасибо) Разобрался)